# Wear it on both your shoulders; wear both the straps, wear your bag with two straps

Tags: word-usage

When kids sling their bags, teachers say:

> Wear it on both your shoulders.
>
> Wear both the straps. (on your shoulders)
>
> Wear your backpack with both straps.

Do these sound natural? I read them being used on different websites to mean the same thing "wear your bag over both shoulders".

Comment: Maybe *"put your backpack all the way on"* would be the most natural way of saying this. If the kid asks for clarification you'd then say *"both shoulders"*.

Answer (score 2):

All your sentences are correct, but if I were talking to children I would say,

> Wear your bag properly.

This depends on a shared understanding of the "proper" way to wear a backpack. If I need to explain the proper way to wear a backpack it would be "on both shoulders". I'd use "properly" as I am trying to persuade the children to do something, so I'm using a rhetorical language. I'm suggesting in my speech that there is a "proper" way to do it, and I'm engaging with them to make them think about what the proper way is and so modify their behaviour.